# Overriding abstract method with generics

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract

I have an abstract base class that is defined like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T>
```

The class contains a definition for the method Get:

```
protected abstract MyBaseClass<T> Get(T id);
```

I create MyClass using MyBaseClass:

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass<string>
```

Now I have to implement `Get`, but don't know how to define it:

```
public override MyClass Get(object id)
```

or

```
public override MyClass Get(string id)
```

In both cases I will have to mention `string` as `T` and I would like to avoid it.

What is the correct way to override `Get` ?

Thank You.

Comment: Try `protected override MyBaseClass<object> Get(object id)` also remove static as they cant be abstract.

Comment: `abstract static` ? Static methods cant be abstract and abstract methods can't be static as well

Comment: what if it's not static? assume it isn't.

Comment: If it isn't static use my code it will work. // Added full answer with both the abstract class and class extending it.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid specifically using `string`? As in `protected override MyBaseClass<string> Get(string id)`

Comment: I will have to use `id` as `string`. How can i convert it without mentioning the type?

Comment: But you are specifically using `string` in `MyClass` definition anyway, so why cant you specifically use it in the overriding method?

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg look at my answer, is that what you wanted? Use string as Id but still returning the MyBaseClass<T> object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you stated the interface you were implementing you specified the generic argument as `string` when you wrote (`: MyBaseClass<string>`), as such the *only* way for you to implement the `Get` method is to use `string` in place of all values for `T`.  If you want users of your class to be able to use other types then you need to make the implementing class generic as well:

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass<T>
{
    protected override MyBaseClass<T> Get(T id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract MyBaseClass<T> Get(T id);
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass<string>
{
    protected override MyBaseClass<string> Get(string id)
    {
        return FindById(id);//implement your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I've posted 17 seconds earlier ; )

Comment: @Tafari You beat me to it :)

Comment: @Yevgeni Grinberg It depends on you, which one you choose for T.

Comment: `MyClass : MyBaseClass<string>` so `string` is correct for this, not `object`.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg you inherited from `MyBaseClass<string>` so you must use `string` anything otherthan string will result in a compile time error. So this **isn't wrong**

Comment: My point is that I already declared `string` as `T` in the definition of `MyClass` and I'm trying to find a way not to do it again for every appearance of `T`.

Comment: You have to I guess, you can use the `public class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass<T> implementation, but still you will have to use <T> when defining your methods and so on.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg: In visual studio you type the word `override` then hit space it will give you auto complete, then you don't have to type `string`... also, if you are worried about needing to change the type the you can do a find and replace

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg Oops, I overlooked it. Check out [Servy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19497194/2530848). you've to go that way

Answer (score 0):

Implement abstaract class as follows:

```
public abstract class  MyBaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract MyBaseClass<T> Get(T id);

    protected abstract MyBaseClass<T> Get(string id);
}
```

And the extending class:

```
class Class1 : MyBaseClass<Object>
{
    protected override MyBaseClass<object> Get(object id)
    {
        return (MyBaseClass<object>) id;
    }

    protected override MyBaseClass<object> Get(string id)
    {
        return FindMyBaseClass(id)
    }
}
```